# Mark range based on identifier

Tags: r, range, extract

This is based on a question I asked yesterday. It got very muddled, so I am trying again with a clearer question.

I have a large data set.

```
>head(raw)

 ps cond pass sample stim gsr
1  1    2    0      0    0 100   
2  1    2    0      1    0 100   
3  1    2    0      2    0 100   
4  1    2    0      3    0 100   
5  1    2    0      4    0 100   
6  1    2    0      5    0 100
```

The $stim column is composed of various periods numbered 1-11 (each period lasts 20 $sample), with longer blocks of 0 (lasting for 140 $sample).

For every $stim==10, I need to mark a subsequent range:

e.g.,

> count(raw$sample[raw$ps==1 & raw$stim==10]) #this counts for 1 subject as an example

```
      x freq
1  1100    1
2  1101    1
3  1102    1
4  1103    1
5  1104    1
6  1105    1
7  1106    1
8  1107    1
9  1108    1
10 1109    1
11 1110    1
12 1111    1
13 1112    1
14 1113    1
15 1114    1
16 1115    1
17 1116    1
18 1117    1
19 1118    1
20 1119    1
```

So I want the beginning of the range to start 10 cells after the last cell with $stim==10 (in this example it is 1119, so we start from 1120. **We need to count 10 from this place:** 1130. The end of the range is 50 $sample from 1130 = 1180.

So. What I think I need is for a new column in my raw file, which marks TRUE those cells to be used in the analysis. In the above example, they would be the range between $sample == 1130 and 1180.

I don't want to go through by hand. I am looking for a more automated way of ticking off the ranges.

I hope it is now clearer what I am aiming for?

Further information:

```
> sort(unique(rle(raw$n.filter)$length))
 40   50  590 1080 1130 1240 1400 1560 1720 1880 2030 2040 2200 2360

> summary(raw$stim)
     0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10     11 
286440   3720   3720   3720   3720   3720   3720   3720   3720   3720   3720   3720 

> summary(raw$stim[raw$ps==1])
   0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11 
1540   20   20   20   20   20   20   20   20   20   20   20 

> summary(raw$stim[raw$ps==186])
   0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11 
1540   20   20   20   20   20   20   20   20   20   20   20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited answer due to an error in previous one:**

There are two ways of getting what you want. One way is vectorized (and fast), the other one is with a loop and slow.

1.Vectorized:

```
tmp <- which(raw$stim == 10)
ltmp <- 1:length(tmp)

raw$n.filter <- FALSE
raw[tmp + 30,"n.filter"] <- TRUE
raw[tmp + 50,"n.filter"] <- TRUE
raw[tmp[ltmp[(ltmp%%20) > 0 & (ltmp%%20) < 11]]+70,"n.filter"] <- TRUE
rle(raw$n.filter)
```

2.With Loop:

```
raw$n.filter <- FALSE

for (counter in 2:(nrow(raw))) {
    if ( (raw[counter-1, "stim"] == 10) & raw[counter, "stim"] != 10) raw[(counter+10):(counter+59),"n.filter"] <- TRUE
}

rle(raw$n.filter)
```

I was too lazy to wait for the loop version to finish. it is the best you copy the result of one version, then run the other and see whether they are `all.equal()`.

Comment: @Henrik Close, but not quite! It seems to be selecting 40 after stim==10. I will look further into your code and see if I can adapt it. Many thanks for the help.

Comment: hmm, thats sounds unlikely. the code in the `[]` within the `c()` should return a vector of length 50 if the sequences of stim == 10 are each 20 long.  
If anything, your comment suggests that the third part of this `c()` sequence is not working.

Comment: @Henrik. My bad. I put in the wrong values. I think yours was doing what I asked, not what I needed. My fault. I will see if I can adapt yours to my needs.

Comment: @ RSoul. Note that my version only works if each stim == 10 run is equally long. If not, this whole approach is not working and you need to use a loop. Please tell me if this is needed and I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Henrik. This appears to have worked: raw[c(which(raw$stim == 10) + 30, which(raw$stim == 10) + 60, (which(raw$stim == 10) + 80)[1:10]),"n.filter"] <- TRUE

Comment: @Henrik. Each stim==10 is equally long (20 $sample). I will hammer what you've given me and hopefully I'm done. Many thanks.

Comment: @Rsoul, Ahh, I see you edited your question. Please see my edit.

Comment: @Henrik. I am not sure what the problem is. Your edited version gives me 10 after stim==10, but ends 10 short (giving me 40, not 50). The version I posted gave me 50. I don't understand it, but that's what the data is showing?

Comment: @Rsoul, hmm, from my toy data I can not reproduce that behavior. Your code should lead to gaps in the runs of TRUE. can you please post the results of `rle(x$n.filter)` from your and my version in your question (that is a suitable test if the code does what you want).

Comment: @Henrik. This is odd. Because my data is so large, I was checking the end of the file. The first $stim==10 (at the beginning) is 50. But subsequent $stim==10 are 40.

Comment: @RSoul sorry, it should have been `rle(raw$n.filter)`. If that is too long please post the beginning of `sort(unique(rle(raw$n.filter)$length))`.

Comment: @Henrik: rle(x$n.filter) gives > rle(ps2b$n.filter)
`Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:373] 1130 50 2030 40 1720 40 1240 40 2360 40 ...
  values : logi [1:373] FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE ...`

Comment: @Henrik. I have added some more details to the bottom of the post. I am right back to being confused. Thanks for the consideration though. :)

Comment: Hmm, that is really weird. I don't see how this could happen with my code. What actually is ps2b? Unless I don't have the data, I can not help you further as I have no idea how this happens.

Comment: @Henrik. ps2b is just another name for the raw data. I have rerun several times now. The first stim==10 it gives 50, but subsequent runs are 40. The datafile is large (10mb), but I've added it to the post, if you're interested? I'm stumped though. I should add: You realise that the range is 10 after stim==10 has ended? Maybe that is the missing 10?

Comment: @RSoul There was an error in my intial version. Now it should work.

Comment: @Henrik. From my number-crunching that appears to be tip-top-tapstic. Many thanks for the hard work and help. Regards.